# Android Lollipop Custom Ringtone, no permission to write

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, ringtone

I recently upgraded to Lollipop 5.0 on my nexus 4. I know that the ringtones folder is system/media/ringtones, but once I copy my music file (which I want to make my ringtone) from my sd card and try to paste it, I lose the permission to paste it write when I leave the sd card folder. So bottom-line, Im not able to write files to my ringtones folder. Please help!

Comment: I think this questions should be moved to http://android.stackexchange.com/ or closed because it's off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, figured it out! I wasnt supposed to store it in tbe system folder.. I was supposed to store in the storage/sdcard/ringtones folder :)